# Generating SQL INSERT from data in Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of records. Columns correspond to fields in a table in a SQL Server database. What is the quickest way to generate an SQL query to insert this data?

Comment: **Option 1:** You should write an app to read **thousands of records** in excel file then loop each row in order to `insert into table` in SQL.
**Option 2:** Just copy then paste into SQL if the order of your columns is correct.

Comment: Better way to import data from excel to `sql-server` if you have permission to import data. Otherwise you can write macro to save text file for each record to generate `INSERT INTO` statement as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Al2110

based on your query, To generating SQL insert from data in excel file that show in below:

```
insert into customers values('" &B3 &"','" &C3& "','"&D3&"');
```

I hope above information will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Import and Export Wizard is a convenient option.